# laravel post route send data to another file

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm new to laravel. I have form on welcome.blade.php with input data

```
<form action='chart.php' method='post'>    
<input type='text' name='job1' class='form-control' id="job1" />
<input name='salary1' type='text' class='form-control' id="salary1" />
<br>
<input type='text' name='job2' class='form-control' id="job2" />
<input name='salary2' type='text' class='form-control' id="salary2" />
```

I want to send the values to chart.blade.php where it make chart ,

I don't know how to make post route

```
 Route::post('chart', function()
{
    return View::make('chart', array('job1' => $job1, 'salary1' => $salary1, 'job2' => $job2, 'salary2' => $salary2));
});
```

Comment: Okay what you have done so far ?

Comment: i added the form action url & rout .weren't appear before

Comment: what about the controller ? do you have any controller for this ? I think you should start with the basics of laravel You have to understand how the routes and form work together. May this will help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing

Comment: no controller.yes u right but i need this soon.I thought I could do like in php pass variables from page to anotef.

Comment: No its not that way but as of now you can change your form action as `route('chart')`  this will generate url for your route chart and it will post your form to this route. Get the posted value as `Input::get('job1')` if you are using the `laravel4.2` if you are using `5.0 or more than that` then your route also need to change. as  `Route::post('chart', function(Request $request)` and get posted values as $request->get('yourInputName')`. But I would suggest first you have look in laravel basic concepts.

Comment: thanks dear.it laravel 5 . I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest form you can use, without using controllers:

In your view:

```
<form action='chart' method='post'>    
<input type='text' name='job1' class='form-control' id="job1" />
<input name='salary1' type='text' class='form-control' id="salary1" />
<br>
<input type='text' name='job2' class='form-control' id="job2" />
<input name='salary2' type='text' class='form-control' id="salary2" />
</form>
```

In your routes:

```
Route::post('chart', function()
{
    extract(request()->all());
    return View::make('chart', array('job1' => $job1, 'salary1' => $salary1, 'job2' => $job2, 'salary2' => $salary2));
});
```

Please note that:

- I renamed the action to match the route name `chart`
- I load the posted values by using `request()->all()`
- I used the PHP `extract()` function to parse each input name into a variable (makes variables out of array keys).